# About the usage of "__GFP_COMP"?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

I found nothing useful but only comment on `__GFP_COMP` through
out the source code of kernel, which says: "`__GFP_COMP` address compound
page metadata."

I googled it, but I'm still confused.

Besides, I called the function `kzalloc` with the argument of `GFP_KERNEL`
on Linux-4.19.82, but the kernel finally complains and points the option
is `GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP|__GFP_ZERO`. I understand why there is an
option of `__GFP_ZERO` and `GFP_KERNEL`, but where does `__GFP_COMP`
come from?

Here is the related code snippet (please refer to [gitlab.denx.de/Xenomai/xenomai/-/blob/v3.1/kernel/cobalt/heap.c](http://gitlab.denx.de/Xenomai/xenomai/-/blob/v3.1/kernel/cobalt/heap.c) line 735):

```c
int xnheap_init(struct xnheap *heap, void *membase, size_t size)
{
    int n, nrpages;
    spl_t s;

    ......    
    nrpages = size >> XNHEAP_PAGE_SHIFT;
    heap->pagemap = kzalloc(sizeof(struct xnheap_pgentry) * nrpages,
                GFP_KERNEL);
    if (heap->pagemap == NULL)
        return -ENOMEM;
    ......

}
```

Here is the implementation of `kzalloc`:

```c
/**
 * kzalloc - allocate memory. The memory is set to zero.
 * @size: how many bytes of memory are required.
 * @flags: the type of memory to allocate (see kmalloc).
 */
static inline void *kzalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
    return kmalloc(size, flags | __GFP_ZERO);
}
```

Here is the most related log which is output by "dmesg" :

```
    page allocation failure: order:9, mode:0x60c0c0
(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=(null)
```

Here is the whole log:

```
[22041.387673] HelloWorld: page allocation failure: order:9,
mode:0x60c0c0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=(null)
    [22041.387678] HelloWorld cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
    [22041.387690] CPU: 3 PID: 27737 Comm: HelloWorld Not tainted
4.19.84
    [22041.387695] I-pipe domain: Linux
    [22041.387697] Call Trace:
    [22041.387711]  dump_stack+0x9e/0xc8
    [22041.387718]  warn_alloc+0x100/0x190
    [22041.387725]  __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xb93/0xbd0
    [22041.387732]  __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x26d/0x2b0
    [22041.387739]  alloc_pages_current+0x6a/0xe0
    [22041.387744]  kmalloc_order+0x18/0x40
    [22041.387748]  kmalloc_order_trace+0x24/0xb0
    [22041.387754]  __kmalloc+0x20e/0x230
    [22041.387759]  ? __vmalloc_node_range+0x171/0x250
    [22041.387765]  xnheap_init+0x87/0x200
    [22041.387770]  ? remove_process+0xc0/0xc0
    [22041.387775]  cobalt_umm_init+0x61/0xb0
    [22041.387779]  cobalt_process_attach+0x64/0x4c0
    [22041.387784]  ? snprintf+0x45/0x70
    [22041.387790]  ? security_capable+0x46/0x60
    [22041.387794]  bind_personality+0x5a/0x120
    [22041.387798]  cobalt_bind_core+0x27/0x60
    [22041.387803]  CoBaLt_bind+0x18a/0x1d0
    [22041.387812]  ? handle_head_syscall+0x3f0/0x3f0
    [22041.387816]  ipipe_syscall_hook+0x119/0x340
    [22041.387822]  __ipipe_notify_syscall+0xd3/0x190
    [22041.387827]  ? __x64_sys_rt_sigaction+0x7b/0xd0
    [22041.387832]  ipipe_handle_syscall+0x3e/0xc0
    [22041.387837]  do_syscall_64+0x3b/0x250
    [22041.387842]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
    [22041.387847] RIP: 0033:0x7ff3d074e481
    [22041.387852] Code: 89 c6 48 8b 05 10 6b 21 00 c7 04 24 00 00 00 a4 8b
38 85 ff 75 43 bb 00 00 00 10 c7 44 24 04 11 00 00 00 48 89 e7 89 d8 0f 05
<bf> 04 00 00 00 48 89 c3 e8 e2 e0 ff ff 8d 53 26 83 fa 26 0f 87 46
    [22041.387855] RSP: 002b:00007ffc62caf210 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX:
0000000010000000
    [22041.387860] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000000010000000 RCX:
00007ff3d074e481
    [22041.387863] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI:
00007ffc62caf210
    [22041.387865] RBP: 00007ff3d20a3780 R08: 00007ffc62caf160 R09:
0000000000000000
    [22041.387868] R10: 0000000000000008 R11: 0000000000000246 R12:
00007ff3d0965b00
    [22041.387870] R13: 0000000001104320 R14: 00007ff3d0965d40 R15:
0000000001104050
    [22041.387876] Mem-Info:
    [22041.387885] active_anon:56054 inactive_anon:109301 isolated_anon:0
                    active_file:110190 inactive_file:91980 isolated_file:0
                    unevictable:9375 dirty:1 writeback:0 unstable:0
                    slab_reclaimable:22463 slab_unreclaimable:19122
                    mapped:101678 shmem:25642 pagetables:7663 bounce:0
                    free:456443 free_pcp:0 free_cma:0
    [22041.387891] Node 0 active_anon:224216kB inactive_anon:437204kB
active_file:440760kB inactive_file:367920kB unevictable:37500kB
isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB mapped:406712kB dirty:4kB
writeback:0kB shmem:102568kB writeback_tmp:0kB unstable:0kB
all_unreclaimable? no
    [22041.387893] Node 0 DMA free:15892kB min:32kB low:44kB high:56kB
active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB
unevictable:0kB writepending:0kB present:15992kB managed:15892kB
mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB
local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
    [22041.387901] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2804 3762 3762
    [22041.387912] Node 0 DMA32 free:1798624kB min:5836kB low:8704kB
high:11572kB active_anon:188040kB inactive_anon:219400kB
active_file:184156kB inactive_file:346776kB unevictable:24900kB
writepending:0kB present:3017476kB managed:2927216kB mlocked:24900kB
kernel_stack:1712kB pagetables:7564kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB
free_cma:0kB
    [22041.387920] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 958 958
    [22041.387930] Node 0 Normal free:11256kB min:1992kB low:2972kB
high:3952kB active_anon:36084kB inactive_anon:218100kB active_file:257220kB
inactive_file:21148kB unevictable:12600kB writepending:4kB
present:1048576kB managed:981268kB mlocked:12600kB kernel_stack:5280kB
pagetables:23088kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:0kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB
    [22041.387938] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
    [22041.387948] Node 0 DMA: 3*4kB (U) 3*8kB (U) 1*16kB (U) 1*32kB (U)
3*64kB (U) 0*128kB 1*256kB (U) 0*512kB 1*1024kB (U) 1*2048kB (M) 3*4096kB
(M) = 15892kB
    [22041.387990] Node 0 DMA32: 14912*4kB (UME) 13850*8kB (UME) 9325*16kB
(UME) 5961*32kB (UME) 3622*64kB (UME) 2359*128kB (UME) 1128*256kB (UME)
524*512kB (M) 194*1024kB (UM) 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 1799872kB
    [22041.388033] Node 0 Normal: 1643*4kB (UME) 71*8kB (UME) 47*16kB (UM)
35*32kB (M) 38*64kB (M) 1*128kB (M) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB
0*4096kB = 11572kB
    [22041.388071] Node 0 hugepages_total=0 hugepages_free=0
hugepages_surp=0 hugepages_size=2048kB
    [22041.388073] 232507 total pagecache pages
    [22041.388077] 7 pages in swap cache
    [22041.388079] Swap cache stats: add 1015, delete 1008, find 0/1
    [22041.388081] Free swap  = 995068kB
    [22041.388083] Total swap = 999420kB
    [22041.388086] 1020511 pages RAM
    [22041.388088] 0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly
    [22041.388090] 39417 pages reserved
    [22041.388092] 0 pages hwpoisoned
```

Comment: When you do `kzalloc(npages, GFP_KERNEL)` are you aware of the fact that `kzalloc` does **not** want a number of pages as parameter, but a size in bytes? That variable name seems to suggest that you are passing the wrong kind of argument. Also, what is its value? That would be useful to know.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Please excuse this clerical error. The correct one should be:"kzalloc(npages*sizeof(struct xnheap_pgentry), GFP_KERNEL);". Here is the related code snippet about the calculation of the aforemetioned value:"nrpages = size >> XNHEAP_PAGE_SHIFT;"(`size` is equivalent to 256KB since size=CONFIG_XENO_OPT_SHARED_HEAPSZ(i.e. 256)*1024 ` , XNHEAP_PAGE_SHIFT` is equivalent to 9 and `sizeof(struct xnheap_pgentry)` equivalent to 12):But as you see if that is right, it should not use `kzalloc` to call so much memory. I read the source code carefully,but I still don't know where goes wrong.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli For the most related code snippet, please refer to <https://gitlab.denx.de/Xenomai/xenomai/-/blob/v3.1/kernel/cobalt/heap.c> line:735. Thank you for your attention to this matter.

Comment: please add the correct code snippet to the question using the "Edit" button below it so that it's clear what you are asking, don't just comment it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli There are so many related code snippets. I could not post all of them. The calculation of `size` isn't straightforward. Many many functions have been called.

Comment: Well ok, but at least change the variable name to make it clear that the funcion is being called correctly.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I have followed your advice and reedited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, `kzalloc(size, flags)` just ends up calling:

```
kmalloc(size, flags | __GFP_ZERO);
```

Thus adding `__GFP_ZERO` to your `GFP_KERNEL`.

What happens next depends on the size of the request. According to what you say in the comments under your post, you should have:

```
size == 256*1024
nrpages == size >> 9 == 512
sizeof(struct xnheap_pgentry) == 12
```

Therefore the final size is `12 * 512 = 6144`, which is larger than [`KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.82/source/include/linux/slab.h#L278) (`4096`). As you correctly point out in the comments, this request is quite large.

As a consequence of this, you enter [this branch in `kmalloc()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.82/source/include/linux/slab.h#L507):

```c
static __always_inline void *kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
    if (__builtin_constant_p(size)) {
        if (size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
            return kmalloc_large(size, flags); // <<<<<<< HERE

    /* ... */
}
```

What happens next is:

1. [`kmalloc_large()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.82/source/include/linux/slab.h#L446) does:

   ```c
   static __always_inline void *kmalloc_large(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
   {
       unsigned int order = get_order(size);
       return kmalloc_order_trace(size, flags, order);
   }
   ```
2. [`kmalloc_order_trace()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.82/source/mm/slab_common.c#L1192) does:

   ```c
   void *kmalloc_order_trace(size_t size, gfp_t flags, unsigned int order)
   {
       void *ret = kmalloc_order(size, flags, order);
       trace_kmalloc(_RET_IP_, ret, size, PAGE_SIZE << order, flags);
       return ret;
   }
   ```
3. And finally [`kmalloc_order()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.82/source/mm/slab_common.c#L1177) does:

   ```c
   /*
    * To avoid unnecessary overhead, we pass through large allocation requests
    * directly to the page allocator. We use __GFP_COMP, because we will need to
    * know the allocation order to free the pages properly in kfree.
    */
   void *kmalloc_order(size_t size, gfp_t flags, unsigned int order)
   {
       void *ret;
       struct page *page;

       flags |= __GFP_COMP; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<< FLAG __GFP_COMP ADDED HERE
       page = alloc_pages(flags, order);
       ret = page ? page_address(page) : NULL;
       kmemleak_alloc(ret, size, 1, flags);
       kasan_kmalloc_large(ret, size, flags);
       return ret;
   }
   ```

So eventually `kmalloc_order()` is the function responsible for adding the `__GFP_COMP` flag, and it does so for implementation-related reasons (in order to be able to correctly `kfree()` those pages afterwards).

What happens next in your specific case is that when `kmalloc_order()` calls `alloc_pages()`, the kernel is not able to allocate the pages and panics. What's the reason for this and how it could be fixed is hard to tell without doing some additional analysis. You could be running out of memory.

Comment: Thank you for that very clear explanation. The aforementioned log shows there is no "order 9 and order 10" memory(see the log about "Node 0 Normal"). Do you have some ideas to make the buddy allocator initializes more memory at the beginning of the system startup to avoid such a problem? Is it a feasible method?

Comment: @John Looking at the dmesg log more closely you are indeed right, that seems way larger than expected. An order of 9 means 2^9 = 512 pages = 2MiB of memory, which does not seem to line up with the numbers you told me. I would suggest you to `printk()` those numbers before the `kzalloc()` call to make sure. Anyway, surely initializing memory at startup it would be a lot less likely to run into such an error, maybe you could also play with `/proc/sys/vm/min_free_kbytes` and similar, I am not sure what would be a recommended good solution though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd try the said methods. One more question, as per the article(https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/KernelMemoryZones), which says[emphasis mine]: "**if you ask for Normal memory on a 64-bit machine and there isn't any but there's lots of DMA32, you'll get DMA32**. It's just that kernel prefers to preserve DMA32 for things that have asked for it specifically". You see, there're free blocks with the corresponding size in the zone of DMA(i.e. **Node 0 DMA: ......2*4096** ). Why doesn't it **use these blocks while there no such free memory block in the zone of normal**?

Comment: @John I'm no expert in kernel memory management, but you're requesting way more than 2*4096 so even if that was the case it wouldn't succeed.

Comment: Excuse me, I misled you. The CONFIG_XENO_OPT_SHARED_HEAPSZ is 81920KB(not the said 256KB). So, `(81920KB>>9)*sizeof(struct xnheap_pgentry)(i.e. 12)` equivalent to 1920KB, just a little than the 2^9 order memory. I think it's an important clue. What do you think about it?

Comment: @John order 2^9 means 2^9 *pages*, not 2^9 bytes. 1920KB is indeed 480 pages and the closest power of two is 2^9 (512). So yeah, now the numbers seem right, but I still don't know what you expect me to say. Your question was "why is `__GFP_COMP` added to my flags?" and I answered that, I don't know much more.

Comment: Yes,  the numbers seem right. I just want to tell you the reason for the problem which we have talked about before(i.e. quote from your reply: "Looking at the dmesg log more closely you are indeed right, that seems way larger than expected. An order of 9 means 2^9 = 512 pages = 2MiB of memory, which does not seem to line up with the numbers you told me." ). Thank you very much. I can almost solve the problem which causes page allocation failure now.